# where should I/and how do I create my 'Directory Structure'

Tags: html, css

Appreciate that this is a VERY basic ask but I am starting the process of learning to code and have started with HTML and CSS. I have been practicing (the basics) in Notepad++ and have come to uploading images but cant do this from my local drive (showing as a broken image), where should I/and how do I create my 'Directory Structure' to enable me to insert images etc? Thanks

```
<html> <body> <img src"images/swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" title="Man swimming butterfly taken from above" /><br /> <img src"../../images/turbo1.jpg" alt="Bike turbo, black and white" /><br /> <img src"C:\Users\garet\Desktop\Coding practise\Images\swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" /><br /> <img src"swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" title="Man swimming butterfly taken from above" /><br /> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: not really sure what is your problems here.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<img src"images/swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" title="Man swimming butterfly taken from above" /><br />
<img src"../../images/turbo1.jpg" alt="Bike turbo, black and white" /><br />
<img src"C:\Users\garet\Desktop\Coding practise\Images\swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" /><br />
<img src"swimmer1.jpeg" alt="Swimming butterfly" title="Man swimming butterfly taken from above" /><br />
</body> 
</html>

Comment: @Gareth - your code is missing the = after `src`. It's supposed to be `<img src="images/swimmer1.jpg">`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no special directory structure to follow if you just have basic HTML.

If you have a folder with, say,

- index.html
- kitten.jpg

and `index.html` contains

```
<html>
  <body> 
    <img src="kitten.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

the lovely little furball should show up no matter where you upload things.

You can structure things however you prefer, just taking into account the relative paths of the files to each other. So if you have a structure like

- index.html
- images/

  - kitten.jpg

then `index.html` must contain

```
<html>
  <body> 
    <img src="images/kitten.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are these images saved in a file on your desktop or online?

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: This is what I thought but I am just receiving the broken picture icon

Comment: @Gareth Okay, now that we have example code – you're missing the `=` after `src` :)